# Overlay image using jQuery append

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am creating an application that will add frame on the main image every time I click the frame.

this is my code:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Panel ID="stage" runat="server" cssClass="containment-wrapper" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
         <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBrowse" runat="server" Height="375px" Width="640px" src="Image/MainImage.png"/>
         <input type='file' id="inpUploader" style="display:none;"/>
</asp:Panel>


<img src="Image/Frames/sampleFrame1.png" class="Frames"/>
<img src="Image/Frames/sampleFrame2.png" class="Frames"/>
<img src="Image/Frames/sampleFrame3.png" class="Frames"/>
```

**CS:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imgBrowse.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('inpUploader').click(); return false;");
    }
```

**JS:**

```
$('.Frames').click(function () {
    var imageClone = $(this).clone();
    $("#stage").append(imageClone);

});
```

The code is appending to the stage but below the main image. This is the sample output of my code:
[image]

And I want to create like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **CSS** class, such as

```
.overlap { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; }
```

Apply it in cloned image

```
var imageClone = $(this).clone().addClass('overlap');
$("#stage").append(imageClone);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/DVc3L/), In demo there are 2 image overlapped.

### EDIT

```
$("#stage").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#inpUploader').trigger('click');
    //or
    $('#inpUploader')[0].click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But can you help me if I will add click event on the main image? After Applying this, I cannot click the main image anymore. I change the image to imageButton.

Comment: @MMakati, Reason You are not able to click on main image is because, Its in background. I will suggest you to attach event on container.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to accomplish this? see edited code. Thanks!

Comment: @MMakati. jQuery Code `$("#stage").click(function () {
    $('#inpUploader').trigger('click');
 //or
 $('#inpUploader')[0].click();
});` try this

Comment: Awesome! Do you know how to put `return false` in your code? The image gets lost because of the postback of the button.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47120/discussion-between-mmakati-and-satpal)